# Handle click event in a table in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a table and I want to click on the row. The row will be highlighted, have a check before it and information of that row will appear if the icon is not the folder.
My project is using angular in a asp.net core project but I don't how to solve this problem.

**My tries**: I have tried Jquery at first and put it in the index but it's not works, then I put it the component html file and not work too.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/5.0.1/css/fabric.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css" />  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="ms-Fabric" dir="ltr">
  <div class="ms-CommandBar" id="canvas">
    <div class="ms-CommandBar-mainArea">
      <div class="ms-CommandButton">
        <button class="ms-CommandButton-button">
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-icon ms-fontColor-purpleLight"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Add"></i></span>
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-label">New</span>
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-dropdownIcon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown"></i></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="ms-CommandButton">
        <button class="ms-CommandButton-button">
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-icon ms-fontColor-purpleLight"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Upload"></i></span>
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-label">Upload</span>
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-dropdownIcon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown"></i></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="ms-CommandButton">
        <button class="ms-CommandButton-button">
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-icon ms-fontColor-purpleLight"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--SyncToPC"></i></span>
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-label">Sync</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="ms-CommandButton">
        <button class="ms-CommandButton-button">
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-icon ms-fontColor-green"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ExcelLogo"></i></span>
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-label">Export to Excel</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="ms-CommandButton">
        <button class="ms-CommandButton-button">
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-icon ms-fontColor-purpleLight"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Flow"></i></span>
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-label">Flow</span>
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-dropdownIcon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown"></i></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="ms-CommandButton">
        <button class="ms-CommandButton-button">
          <span class="ms-CommandButton-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--More"></i></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ms-Breadcrumb">
        <ul class="ms-Breadcrumb-list">
          <li class="ms-Breadcrumb-listItem">
            <a href="#" class="ms-Breadcrumb-itemLink">Documents</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <table class="ms-Table">
        <thead class="ms-Table-head">
          <tr>
            <th><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--checkbox"></i></th>
            <th><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Page"></i></th>
            <th>
              Name<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown"></i>
            </th>
            <th>Modified<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown"></i></th>
            <th>Modified By<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown"></i></th>
            <th><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Add"></i>Add column</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="exTr" (click)="Set">
            <td id="icon"><i class=""></i></td>
            <td><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--FabricFolderFill"></i></td>
            <td>CAS</td>
            <td>April 30</td>
            <td>Megan Bowen</td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="exTr" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" (click)="set">
            <td><i class="ms-Icon ms-Check-circle"></i></td>
            <td>
              <span class="ms-fontColor-green">
                <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ExcelDocument"></i>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>CoasterAndBargelLoading.xslx</td>
            <td>A few seconds ago</td>
            <td>Administrator MOD</td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="exTr" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" (click)="set">
            <td><i class="ms-Icon ms-Check-circle"></i></td>
            <td>
              <span class="ms-fontColor-green">
                <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ExcelDocument"></i>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>RevenueByServices.xslx</td>
            <td>A few seconds ago</td>
            <td>Administrator MOD</td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="exTr" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" (click)="set">
            <td><i class="ms-Icon ms-Check-circle"></i></td>
            <td>
              <span class="ms-fontColor-green">
                <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ExcelDocument"></i>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>RevenueByServices2016.xslx</td>
            <td>A few seconds ago</td>
            <td>Administrator MOD</td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="exTr" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" (click)="set">
            <td><i class="ms-Icon ms-Check-circle"></i></td>
            <td>
              <span class="ms-fontColor-green">
                <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ExcelDocument"></i>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>RevenueByServices2017.xslx</td>
            <td>A few seconds ago</td>
            <td>Administrator MOD</td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3 collapse" id="demo">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>

  

  <script type="text/javascript">
            var CommandBarElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-CommandBar");
            for (var i = 0; i < CommandBarElements.length; i++) {
              new fabric['CommandBar'](CommandBarElements[i]);
            }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
            var BreadcrumbHTML = document.querySelector('.ms-Breadcrumb');
            var Breadcrumb = new fabric['Breadcrumb'](BreadcrumbHTML);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
            var ButtonElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-Button");
            for (var i = 0; i < ButtonElements.length; i++) {
              new fabric['Button'](ButtonElements[i], function() {
                // Insert Event Here
              });
            }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
            var TableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-Table");
            for (var i = 0; i < TableElements.length; i++) {
                new fabric['Table'](TableElements[i]);
            }
  </script>
  <script>
            var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
            var height = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
  </script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

The following code is on a file name doc.component.html

First try:
I add the following code in the index.html file and have an error $ is not defined:

```
 <script>
  $(".exTr").click(function () {
    $("#icon").attr("class", "ms-Icon ms-Icon--checkboxCheck");
  });
</script>
```

Second try:
I add the following code in the doc.component.ts and some neccessary thing in doc.component.html but it not work:

```
set() {
    var element = document.activeElement.firstElementChild;
    var attr = document.createAttribute("class");
    attr.value = "ms-Icon ms-Icon--checkboxCheck";
    element.attributes.setNamedItem(attr);
}
```

Comment: Show some code about what have you tried before and where were you stuck. For better understanding of problem for you and others too.

Comment: Show some sample code, or  Plunkr edit. PLease take this answer for a key  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541671/angular-click-event-on-a-generated-table-cell

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: why are you using jQuery with angular? That is the wrong approach in first place. Usually we don't also have any script tags in template. We handle things in component. Also we don't have `head`, `body` in template, it should only be on the index file. please start with the tutorial to understand the basics of angular since you are doing many things wrong at the moment.https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use angular, you should know that it have hostlistener directives. You may use  and found your row when you clicked:

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
 const target: any = e.target;
        if (target.classList.contains('your_class')) {
                do something
        }
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you very much